# Iptables and APF

Tags: linux, iptables, firewall

I have a small Linux appliance where I put the iptables rule in as:

```
iptables -R INPUT 4 -i eth0 -s XXX.XX.XX.0/24 -j ACCEPT
```

I do a:

```
 iptables -L -v -n | more
```

I see the rule, and it's working.

```
service iptables save
```

But as soon as I reboot the rule is gone.

I noticed the system was also using APF, As soon as I turned this off all run levels this was working.  Any thoughts? How to allow subnets in APF. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct option of iptables to make rules permanent. You can use iptables-save and iptables-restore instead.

Save iptables rules to a file using following command:

```
$  iptables-save > /etc/iptables.conf
```

Then add the following in `/etc/rc.local` to reload the rules in every reboot.

```
$  iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.conf
```

Comment: I've tried that still no love. The save seems to work when I turned of APF off all runlevels.

Comment: Most strange, there is no reason for a restore command not to work. Are you sure it runs on start-up ?

Comment: Actually, it did work I didn't have it in rc.local. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Glad it worked; please mark the answer as correct so others may see it easy if needed.